# How to perform a reduced knapsack problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem statement that seems to be a reduced version of the knapsack problem, but I don't know how do it in Mathematica.

The problem is as follows:
Given a set, S, of integers (e.g {a,b,c,...}) and a specific integer T, find all the possible combinations of the elements of S that sum exactly to T. (e.g returns {a,d,e} and {e,f} because a+d+e=T and e+f=T).

Comment: Please add a specific example. Also, is `KnapsackSolve` not handling this?

Comment: An example such as ```s={1,2,4,5}; t=6; (*output: {{1,5},{2,4}} *)```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Select[Subsets[s], Tr@# == t&]
```

Should accomplish what you're after.

If you'd like to allow multiset results,

```
IntegerPartitions[t, All, s]
```

Comment: You could also use [`ResourceFunction["SelectSubsets"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SelectSubsets) if memory usage becomes an issue _(see Properties & Relations section)_.

Comment: Wow. That's amazing. A one-liner for a combinatorics problem. Thank you. I made a slight change to fit better with my understanding, ```Select[Subsets[s], Total@# == t &]```